# paypal express checkout refund REFUNDSTATUS

Tags: paypal-ipn, express-checkout, paypal

To refund useing express checkout there is [refundTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_SOAP/) method.
One of fields it returns: REFUNDSTATUS which can have values: instant and delayed.
If ACK Success and REFUND_STATUS instant, it means that refund is successful.
What does delayed mean? Does it mean that refunding is pending and ipn will be received?
If so what ipn will be sent if refund is successful and when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

> PENDINGREASON
>
> Reason that the refund payment status is delayed. It is one of the
>   following values:
>
> none – The refund status is instant.
>
> echeck – The refund status is delayed.
>
> regulatoryreview - The payment is pending while we make sure it meets
>   regulatory requirements. You will be contacted again in 24-72 hours
>   with the outcome of the review.

If the status is pending you should also get an update when the status updates.

Comment: What do you mean pending status? REFUND_STATUS can be only instant or delayed. Do you mean that delayed means that it is pending and ipn will be recieved later?

Comment: If the `REFUND_STATUS` is delayed there should be `PENDINGREASON` as well.